# one time hibernate sessionFactory creation

Tags: hibernate

i have  a problem with my hibernate query
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
sess =sessionFactory.openSession();
 i call it in every function ,how can i avoid it  an   create  sessionFactory  only once

Answer (score 0):

You simply create instance once per application, store reference and provide method to access it. What is right way and place to do this depends perfectly about your application.

This is one way:

```
public final class SessionFactoryProvider {
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    static {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    private SessionFactoryProvider() {
    }
}
```

Additionally it can be that you want to add some extra information collection and catching and re-throwing possible exception from static initializer block.